# i want to use selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium

```
@RequestMapping(value="scraping")
public String scraping() {
    String DRIVER_ID = "webdriver.chrome.driver";
    String DRIVER_PATH = "C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe";  
    
    System.setProperty(DRIVER_ID,DRIVER_PATH);
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();        
    String base_url="https://www.google.com";
    
    try {
        driver.get(base_url);       
        WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));   
        webElement.sendKeys("weather");
        webElement.submit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "hi";
}
```

this worked in @SpringBootApplication.

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver() makes an error below.

> 2022-09-13 14:35:37.239 ERROR 19380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;]
> with root cause
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
> ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]    at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:123)
> ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]    at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromeDriver.java:118)
> ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]    at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:106)
> ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]    at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:93)
> ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]    at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:48)
> ~[selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.4.jar:na]    at
> com.pop.scraping.controller.ScrapingController.scraping(ScrapingController.java:37)
> ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_333]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_333]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_333]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_333]   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
> ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
> ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_333]

how can i resolve this?

Comment: The part "`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(...)`" means that you do not have Google Guava on your classpath, but it is required by Selenium. Can you check the project dependency tree to see if it's there and in which version? If you're building a single uberjar, can you check that it also contains the transitive dependencies of your direct dependencies? I assume you're using Maven or Gradle for your dependency management...

Comment: i was using selenuim java 3.141.59 but after i changed it to 4.1.1, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating Selenium to a newer version, I experienced similar issues a while ago

Comment: thank you. i updated to 4.1.1 and it works